# Programmatically create RadioButton with ToggleButton style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Question: How create same button programmaticly in code behind without xaml

XAML:

```
<RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"/>
```

I am try to make button something like this
C#:

```
RadioButton radioButt = new RadioButton();
radioButt.Style = new Style(typeof(ToggleButton);
```

But when i create button in code behind the visual they not changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton() { Content = "Radio button " + i, IsChecked = i == 0  };
        rb.Checked += (sender, args) => 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pressed " + ( sender as RadioButton ).Tag );
        };
        rb.Unchecked += (sender, args) => { /* Do stuff */ };
        rb.Tag = i;

        MyStackPanel.Children.Add( rb );
     }
}
```

And in `XAML`:

```
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"
           TargetType="RadioButton"/>
```

Working code:

Here is my `XAML` CODE:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}"
       TargetType="RadioButton"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <StackPanel Name="MyStackPanel">

        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And `cs` file:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                RadioButton rb = new RadioButton() { Content = "Radio button " + i, IsChecked = i == 0 };
                rb.Checked += (sender, args) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Pressed " + (sender as RadioButton).Tag);
                };
                rb.Unchecked += (sender, args) => { /* Do stuff */ };
                rb.Tag = i;

                MyStackPanel.Children.Add(rb);
            }
        }  
  }
}
```

Output with Togglebutton style
[image: Output with Togglebutton style]

---

Output without Togglebutton style
[image: Output without Togglebutton style]

Comment: without use XAML it's impossible create this button ?